# How do I tell if my UEFI bios System is running Secure Boot?

Tags: windows-10

I have a machine that I want to know if it was running in Secure Boot Mode or if it was running like the old BIOS machines do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a PowerShell Command Prompt and run as Administrator

Run PowerShell command: “Confirm-SecureBootUEFI”

It will return either "True" or "False"

For more information see my detailed blog post:
http://mythoughtsonit.com/2014/05/how-to-tell-if-your-uefi-system-is-running-secure-boot/